# Can we make case milestone record completion date uneditable for some users?

Tags: case, servicecloud, entitlements, casemilestone

I was trying to hide the case milestone completion date for some profiles. I tried using page layout read-only option and we can't set field-level security for case milestone. Also, we can't write a trigger or validation rule on case milestone. Is there a possible way to make case milestone completion date as uneditable for some users?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late to answer but this will help all those who are looking for solution of this as i couldn't found it anywhere else. So, we can make Completion date field on Case Milestone object by Validation rule and the page layout as well, You just have to switch to Classic, go to Setup, search for Case Milestone in Quick find and there you will find this object and its page layout and Validation rules.